My blog singidione.blogspot.com home page is not working in mobile mode
My blog's home page is not functioning properly in mobile mode, although it works well in desktop mode. All other pages function correctly in both mobile and desktop views. This issue has been occurring recently.
I would like to resolve this problem.enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
